# Pre-allocation of array of array

Tags: arrays, julia, allocation

In julia, one can pre-allocate an array of a given `type` and `dims` with

```
A = Array{<type>}(undef,<dims>)
```

example for a 10x10 matrix of floats

```
A = Array{Float64,2}(undef,10,10)
```

However, for array of array pre-allocation, it does not seem to be possible to provide a pre-allocation for the underlying arrays.
For instance, if I want to initialize a vector of `n` matrices of complex floats I can only figure this syntax,

```
A = Vector{Array{ComplexF64,2}}(undef, n)
```

but how could I preallocate the size of each Array in the vector, except with a loop afterwards ? I tried e.g.

```
A = Vector{Array{ComplexF64,2}(undef,10,10)}(undef, n)
```

which obviously does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the cases like you have described you need to use comprehension:

```
a = [Matrix{ComplexF64}(undef, 2,3) for _ in 1:4]
```

This allocates a `Vector` of `Array`s. In Julia's comprehension you can iterate over more dimensions so higher dimensionality is also available.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that "allocate" means "give me a contiguous chunk of memory, of size exactly `blah`".  For an array of arrays, which is really a contiguous chunk of pointers to other contiguous chunks, this doesn't really make sense in general as a combined operation -- the latter chunks might just totally differ.

However, by stating your problem, you make clear that you actually have more structural information: you know that you have `n` 10x10 arrays.  This really is a 3D array, conceptually:

```
A =  Array{Float64}(undef, n, 10, 10)
```

At that point, you can just take slices, or better: views along the first axis, if you need an array of them:

```
[@view A[i, :, :] for i in axes(A, 1)]
```

This is a length `n` array of `AbstractArrays` that in all respects behave like the individual 10x10 arrays you wanted.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to define `A` as `Array{Float64}(undef, 10, 10, n)` and loop over the third dimension due to the column major ordering of julia ?

Comment: I agree, that might be better in terms of efficiency.

Comment: I just noticed that you might even use [EllipsisNotation.jl](https://github.com/ChrisRackauckas/EllipsisNotation.jl) for this: `A[.., i]`.